# Django How would I filter Friend objects elegantly by name when using the built in User model?

Tags: python, django

I am learning by building and have a little FriendShip class. In one of my views, I want to filter the FriendShips such that my user is shown a list of all friendships he or she is involved in.

To give you an idea, something like this that has valid syntax:

`relevant_friends_list = FriendShip.objects.filter(request.user.username == creator || request.user.username == friend)`

But you can't just do that since friend and creator are user objects.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class FriendShip(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="friendship_creator_set")
    friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="friend_set")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.creator.username + " | " + self.friend.username
```

If I were to mimic the tutorial, I would add properties like creator_name = models.charField(...) and set that equal to User.username or something. But that sounds like I'm overthinking things, and it just feels like django would have a minimal-line solution. Thanks for your time

Comment: It is not related to your problem but, I would define `friendship` as a `ManyToManyField` with [`symmetrical`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) value being set to `True` in order to maintain bi-directional relationship between users. Because, if I am your friend, then you are my friend too.

Comment: @ozgur Hello, I'm trying to make it symmetrical but I get `Many-to-many fields with intermediate tables must not be symmetrical.` Do you know of a solution or link to implement symmetry quickly? Thanks if needed I can ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed overthinking. You can filter by model objects, and since you want an OR operation, you can use Q objects like so:

```
from django.db.models import Q

user = request.user
conditions = Q(creator=user) | Q(friend=user)
relevant_friends_list = FriendShip.objects.filter(conditions)
```

Note that request.user is only available inside a view where the request object is available.